# Unpermitted parameters nested attributes - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm trying to submit a form to 2 tables but somehow I got this syntax error `unexpected '\n'` at this line `joins: ['sources'], :landslide_id` and `found unpermitted parameter: sources` in landslide params. Here's all the files

**Models**

```
class Landslide < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sources, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sources

class Source < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :landslide
end
```

**landslides_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @landslide = Landslide.new
    @landslide.sources.build
  end

  # POST /landslides
  def create
    @landslide = Landslide.new(landslide_params)

    @landslide.save
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_landslide
      render json: Landslide.find(params[:total_id]),
             joins: ['sources'], :landslide_id
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def landslide_params
      params.require(:landslide).permit(:start_date, :continent, :country, :location, :landslide_type, :lat, :lng, :mapped, :trigger, :spatial_area, :fatalities, :injuries, :notes, sources_attributes: [ :url, :text ])
    end
```

**sources_controller.rb**

```
    def set_source
      @source = Source.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def source_params
      params.require(:source).permit(:url, :text)
    end
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for :landslide, :url => {:controller => 'landslides', :action => 'create'} do |f|
#something
       %fieldset
        %legend Source
        = f.fields_for :sources do |s|
          .form-group.row
            %label.col-sm-2.col-form-label{for: "textinput"}URL
            .col-sm-10
              = s.text_field :url, class: "form-control"
          .form-group.row
            %label.col-sm-2.col-form-label{for: "textinput"}Text
            .col-sm-10
              = s.text_field :text, class: "form-control"
```

**Request**

```
    {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"W3m2dLTGyuPCbP6+pStWDfgpIbPzGdl4tvf01vMAbyozzkimqlXH4B/RtwBcsLb+iiBqms7EHagY+Anbpo4zNg==",
 "landslide"=>
  {"start_date(3i)"=>"27",
   "start_date(2i)"=>"4",
   "start_date(1i)"=>"2017",
   "continent"=>"Africa",
   "country"=>"Country",
   "location"=>"Location",
   "landslide_type"=>"1",
   "lat"=>"1",
   "lng"=>"1",
   "mapped"=>"False",
   "spatial_area"=>"1",
   "fatalities"=>"1",
   "injuries"=>"1",
   "notes"=>"1",
   "trigger"=>"1",
   "sources"=>{"url"=>"url", "text"=>"text"}},
 "button"=>""}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Add the whole log from the request including the params hash and your entire form. Its not clear exactly what you where doing.

Comment: PS don't do this `%label.col-sm-2.col-form-label{for: "textinput"}Text`. Use the Rails helper `f.label` instead - you're setting the wrong `for` attribute - it should be the same as the `name` attribute on the input. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Request log and screenshot updated

Comment: Is that really the form? There is no way `= f.fields_for :sources` will give that params hash. Please include the code in its entirety.

Comment: Well I fixed the problem. Now I'm having another bug [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669655/rails-nested-attributes-children-doesnt-save/43672550?noredirect=1#comment74402747_43672550).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**found unpermitted parameter: sources**

Based on your form, it looks like sources are inside a param called sources rather than sources_attributes. Edit your `landslide_params`, changing `sources_attributes` to sources.

May I ask what `set_landslide` is trying to render, or correct me if I am wrong below? Placing `joins` on a new line causes the error. I am thinking you're trying to do something like:

```
landslide = Landslide.find(params[:total_id])
render json: landslide.to_json(:include => { :sources => { landslide_params[:sources] }})
```

Which would give you a json with the landslide object and a sources array. The landslide id should be within the landslide object. This of course assumes that's what you were going for.

Comment: If the form actually is as posted in the question it should give the params nested in `sources_attributes`. Thats what `fields_for` does. I originally pointed the OP in the right direction in another question but he just seems to copy-pasting stuff whilly nillly.

Comment: Seems there is a sources param though, so there's certainly something missing from this picture.