# Rails - Unpermitted nested children parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, accepts-nested-attributes

The parent is saved but the children isn't. If I add `landslide.sources.create`, it does create a row in `sources` table with the correct `landslide_id` but all the other columns are null. Here's the files:

**landslide_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @landslide = Landslide.new
    @landslide.sources.build
  end

  def create
    landslide = Landslide.new(landslide_params)
    landslide.save
  end

  def landslide_params
      params.require(:landslide).permit(:start_date, :continent, :country, :location, :landslide_type, :lat, :lng, :mapped, :trigger, :spatial_area, :fatalities, :injuries, :notes, source_attributes: [ :url, :text ])
  end
```

**sources_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    source = Source.new
  end

  def create
    source = Source.new(source_params)

    source.save
  end

  def source_params
    params.require(:source).permit(:url, :text)
  end
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for :landslide, :url => {:controller => 'landslides', :action => 'create'} do |f|

  .form-inputs
    %form#landslideForm
      #Fields
   %fieldset
        %legend Source
        = f.fields_for :sources do |s|
          .form-group.row
            = s.label :url, class: 'col-sm-2 col-form-label'
            .col-sm-10
              = s.text_field :url, class: "form-control"
          .form-group.row
            = s.label :text, class: 'col-sm-2 col-form-label'
            .col-sm-10
              = s.text_field :text, class: "form-control"


      .form-actions
        = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary col-sm-offset-5", id: "submitButton"
```

**landslide.rb and source.rb**

```
class Source < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :landslide, inverse_of: :sources
end

class Landslide < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sources, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :landslide
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sources
```

** routes.rb **

```
  resources :landslides do
    resources :sources
  end
```

Comment: try change `= f.fields_for :sources do |s|` to `= f.fields_for :source_attributes do |s|`

Comment: Still same problem though...

Comment: Could show your models?

Comment: @fangxing models updated

Comment: Stop asking the same question over and over. This is not an acceptable behaviour. You need to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and stop leaving core bits of information out of it. The reason you are getting the param `source` is not in the code here or the other identical question.

Comment: It's something with this line `= form_for :landslide, :url => {:controller => 'landslides', :action => 'create'} do |f|
` and routing I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code it is expected to create `source` with null field. Because of `landslide.sources.create` here you are creating `source` with out any attribute values.

To successfully save `source` follow the following step.

1. build `source` on controller's new method

   `def new
       @landslide = Landslide.new
       @landslide.sources.build
   end`
2. User `@landslide` (declared on `new`) on the form 
   `= form_for @landslide` and other thing will remain same.
3. remove `landslide.sources.create` from your `landslide_controller.rb` because `source` will save automatically after saving `landslide`.

Hope above changes will solve your problem.

Comment: I changed to yours and it doesn't even create a new sample of `source`

Comment: Please share your `params` data or if it opensource you can share your github or other link.

Comment: `def landslide_params
      params.require(:landslide).permit(:start_date, :continent, :country, :location, :landslide_type, :lat, :lng, :mapped, :trigger, :spatial_area, :fatalities, :injuries, :notes, source_attributes: [ :url, :text ])
  end` landslide params

Comment: `def source_params
      params.require(:source).permit(:url, :text)
    end` source params

Comment: Can we discuss in chat anyway?

Comment: Ok, share your mail

Comment: http://www.e-chat.co/room/206175

Comment: Sorry, can you go back to the room please?